# Is there a package that allows a citation style of [Author, year] [number]?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I want to display citations using a mix of [apalike and ieeetr](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Bibtex_bibliography_styles) styles, something like:

> [Chaitin, 1992 [3]]

Is there a BibTeX or Biblatex package that supports this style? (Or a way to tweak BibTeX to behave like this?)

Comment: Why? The purpose of the label is to enable the reader to find the entry in the bibliography. Why complicate and confuse things? If I saw that, I would wonder whether: this was the third source cited written by Chaitin and published in 1992 (a weird alternative to `Chaitrin, 1992a`) or a strange way of presenting a page/chapter/section number (oddly formatted way to say `Chaitrin, 1992, p. 3` or `Chaitrin 1992, 3`). And I would be immediately distracted from whatever you wanted to say and annoyed by the fact that you'd decided to make it difficult for me to understand you.

Comment: I agree with cfr that this is quite weird. It combines the `numeric` and `authoryear` styles but does not offer an additional value. One of [3] or "Chaitin, 1992" (if done correctly) is enough to identify the citation uniquely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with `biblatex`. If we use `numeric` we only need to enhance the bibmacro `cite` a bit to include the name and year.

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{hardbrackets}{[#1]}
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printnames{labelname}%
    \setunit{\nameyeardelim}%
    \printfield{year}%
    \setunit{\addspace}
    \printtext[hardbrackets]{%
      \printfield{prefixnumber}%
      \printfield{labelnumber}%
      \ifbool{bbx:subentry}
        {\printfield{entrysetcount}}
        {}}}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber]{biblatex}      
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{hardbrackets}{[#1]}
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printnames{labelname}%
    \setunit{\nameyeardelim}%
    \printfield{year}%
    \setunit{\addspace}
    \printtext[hardbrackets]{%
      \printfield{prefixnumber}%
      \printfield{labelnumber}%
      \ifbool{bbx:subentry}
        {\printfield{entrysetcount}}
        {}}}}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson} and \cite{worman,geer}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

Answer (score 3):

You can try this in bibtex:

```
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
```

and use `\citep` instead of `\cite`

Comment: Are you sure that this will generate citation call-outs of the form the OP wants?