# How to add year in my numeric citation style?

Tags: biblatex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
backend=bibtex,
bibstyle=numeric,
citestyle=numeric,
natbib=true
]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblio}

\begin{document}
\citet{federico2014reserve}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The .bib file is omitted here.
And this will give:

> Federico, Vegh, and Vuletin [1].

I want a 'Author-year-number' style of citation like this:

> Federico, Vegh, and Vuletin 2014 [1].

Is there a way to do so in biblatex? Thanks.

Comment: `\textcite{<key>}`, but usually you don't mix Harvard and Vancouver.

Comment: The option `citestyle=authoryear` should be enough.

Comment: @Johannes_B: It doesn't work...

Comment: @Bernard: 'citestyle=authoryear' will drop the number index.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense, but see [Is there a package that allows a citation style of Author, year number?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/279408/35864) and [BibLaTeX citing style](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/135011/35864)

Comment: @moewe Thanks, I see the point. I want this way because I like the numeric citation while most people like the authoryear, so maybe this is a middle way...

Comment: I think what is liked by most people depends on what field you are in, in mathematics and the sciences a numeric style is very prevalent, while in the humanities I tend to see author-year styles or similar.

Answer (score 1):

A style like this doesn't make much sense to me. You give up the one big advantage of a numeric style: unintrusiveness. Since you add the author and year the citation gets longer, and the numeric label doesn't add any further information that the author-year part can't give you (if done properly, of course).

That said, you can just add the name and year to the `cite` macro, but then we also need to move about the brackets.

```
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addspace}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printnames{labelname}%
    \setunit{\nameyeardelim}%
    \printfield{year}%
    \setunit{\addspace}%
    \printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
      \printfield{prefixnumber}%
      \printfield{labelnumber}}%
    \ifbool{bbx:subentry}
      {\printfield{entrysetcount}}
      {}}}
```

Note that this redefines the `\cite` command and not `\textcite`/`\citet`.

In total

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
backend=bibtex,
style=numeric,
natbib=true
]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}

\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addspace}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printnames{labelname}%
    \setunit{\nameyeardelim}%
    \printfield{year}%
    \setunit{\addspace}%
    \printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
      \printfield{prefixnumber}%
      \printfield{labelnumber}}%
    \ifbool{bbx:subentry}
      {\printfield{entrysetcount}}
      {}}}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

Comment: Thank you very much. I see the point and I agree it is strange.