# Modify \cite to [Number](Author+Year)

Tags: biblatex, citing

My university want to use a cite style mixture from Harvard and Numeric style.
Number
I only get [Number (Author+Year)] with my example instead of [ Number ] (Author+Year). So I have some issues with brackets.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=12pt,parskip]{scrbook}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Layout
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%
\usepackage[labelfont={bf}]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
\usepackage[]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}          
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Seitenränder und Abstände
\geometry{
    textwidth=150mm,
    textheight=220mm,
    top=40mm,
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Literaturverzeichnis
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[german=guillemets]{csquotes}
%
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,maxnames=5,minnames=5,maxcitenames=2,mincitenames=1,datamodel=eprint-hal]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
      \printtext[hardbrackets]{%
      \printfield{prefixnumber}%
      \printfield{labelnumber}%
      \ifbool{bbx:subentry}
        {\printfield{entrysetcount}}
        {}}
    \printtext[parens]{%
    \printnames{labelname}%
    \setunit{\nameyeardelim}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}
    \printfield{year}%
}}}
%
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}


ba bla
\cite{springer}
%Literaturverzeichnis
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title=Literaturverzeichnis]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the code that you are using (probably from [Is there a package that allows a citation style of [Author, year] [number]?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/279408/35864)) the brackets are implicitly added by `\cite` via its wrapper command. This is not something we want for your application, because we have different types of brackets.

It appears to me that it would be easiest to define a new `\cite` command so that we get full control over the brackets. The remainder of the approach is similar to [Is there a package that allows a citation style of [Author, year] [number]?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/279408/35864).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
\usepackage[german=guillemets]{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=numeric,
  maxbibnames=5, minbibnames=5,
  maxcitenames=2, mincitenames=1,
]{biblatex}

\newbibmacro*{naycite}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printtext[brackets]{%
      \printfield{labelprefix}%
      \printfield{labelnumber}%
      \ifbool{bbx:subentry}
        {\printfield{entrysetcount}}
        {}}
    \setunit{\addspace}%
    \printtext[parens]{%
      \printnames{labelname}%
      \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
      \printdate}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\naycite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{naycite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\naycites}{\naycite}{\multicitedelim}
\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{nay}{\naycite}{\naycites}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{autocite=nay}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
lorem \autocite{springer}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title=Literaturverzeichnis]
\end{document}
```

[image: lorem [1] (Sigfridsson und Ryde 1998) lorem [2] (Springer 1950)]

If you want bigger brackets around the entire expression you could try something like

```
\newrobustcmd*{\mkbibbiggerbrackets}[1]{%
  {\large[}#1{\large]}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\naycite}[\mkbibbiggerbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{naycite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

Not that I'd recommend it in any shape or form.

Comment: Thanks for your support and the quick response. I hoped to fined a solution were I can still use \cite (just in case I want to change it back to calssic numeric or whatever) but maybe this is the best solution. Or is possible to change it to ([2] Springer,1950) and still use \cite?

Comment: @ArminMeise Actually, `\autocite` makes it *extremely* easy to switch back to a different citation style. Just change `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{autocite=nay}` in the example to `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{autocite=plain}` to get numeric citations with just one simple change. (It should be trivial to change your existing document from `\cite` to `\autocite` as every good editor has a search-and-replace feature.)

Comment: Of course it is also possible to adapt my answer to modify `\cite` instead of `\autocite`, but I really want to advertise the advantages of `\autocite`.

Comment: Thank you! Youre right, it is easy to switch from cite to autocite and thats the best solution for me.

Comment: Is it also possible with your solution to do something like [[2](Springer 1950)] but the first and last bracket should be bigger then the bracket around [2]. Any Ideas? Hope you can help me ;-)

Comment: @ArminMeise I'm guessing it should be possible, but before I edit the answer, are you really sure this is what your university wants? (And also what you want?) The number of brackets is already quite large and adding another pair just makes the citation look ridiculous. (It already looks *very* unusual due to the fact that it essentially combines two citation styles for a lot of redundancy. I have never seen a published paper or serious book using such a style.)

Comment: I know, it is a lot of redundancy but I thought [[2](Springer 1950)] looks maybe better then [2](Springer 1950)

Comment: @ArminMeise See the edit. I don't really think the additional brackets make things better, but if you insist ... (As you requested I made the additional brackets slightly bigger, which I find not very elegant, but...)

Comment: thanks a lot! you realy helped me!

Comment: I tried your modified and it works realy fine! Thanks again. Your right about the bracket size, it looks a little bit ridiculous. Maybe it is possible to change the font size of autocite, so that the outer bracket is in the same size like the text and the [2](Springer 1950) font size is a little smaller? maybe this looks more compacted. but only in the text and not in the biblography

Comment: @ArminMeise Try `\newrobustcmd*{\mkbibbiggerbrackets}[1]{[{\small#1}]}` then. But in the end I still think this is a lipstick-on-a-pig situation. The citation style itself is so unwieldy (and I would argue flawed) that cosmetic changes like this don't make a huge difference.

Comment: but that changed only the outer brackets to small right? but the input like [2](Springer 1950) should also be onefont size smaller

Comment: and I got an error : ! LaTeX Error: Command \mkbibbiggerbrackets already defined.

Comment: @ArminMeise Well, you need to *replace* the previous definition of `\mkbibbiggerbrackets`.